# Determine if object is or derives from specific Type?

Tags: c#, types, comparison

I'm looking for the `is` operator, except that the type operand (right) is dynamic.

```
public static bool Is(this object value, Type type)
{      
  if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(type, "type");
  if (value == null) return false;

  var valueType = value.GetType();
  return valueType == type || valueType.IsSubclassOf(type)
    || valueType implements interface
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing it?

I tried using `IsAssignableFrom`, but it [doesn't seem to be working](http://rextester.com/CRG75144):

```
var x = "asdf";
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(object)));
Console.WriteLine(x is object);
```

Comment: In regards to your update: You used it wrong, should be `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())`

Comment: @BrokenGlass, please vote to close instead of downvoting. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote - and @Freed I was referring to the specific example linked in the question

Comment: @Freed whatever, my mistake. Please vote to close this question instead of just downvoting. This should be deleted.

Comment: @BrokenGlass u didnt upvote to make it zero :p

Comment: @Shimmy, I didn't downvote either, it looks like a perfectly acceptable question to me. You may want to update it and delete the part saying it doesn't work however.

Comment: I think it's a fine question with a suitable answer. I've "tamed" down the end of the post and moved the example code inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better way, you just have to reverse your problem. Instead of asking if valueType is a subclass of type, check if type is assignable from valueType. Luckily, there is  a call to do exactly that, see [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)